# Barcode reading using ipad camera in web application

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, barcode-scanner

I have requirement to read barcode using ipad or IOS device camera in my web application.
i dont know how to implement that. Is there any open source plugin or library which i can use and implement that.Thank you all!!!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can use Zxing library for barcode scanning